# React ¿Cómo instalo los repositorios?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

Estoy descargando de github un sistema en React y cuando lo tengo listo en el editor de codigo no estan los repositorios.

¿Cómo los instalo?

Comment: ¿ya hiciste un `npm install`?

Comment: ¿De dónde jalas los repositorios?¿Usas Node o Deno de casualidad?

Comment: Crei que podia hacer `npm init` pero no resulto. Si, estoy usando Node

Comment: @BetaM voy a probar, gracias!

Comment: con `npm init` inicializas un archivo `package.json` pero no bajas los repositorios pendientes

Comment: Gracias BetaM, se estan instalando los repo

Comment: PERFECTO, si te resulta no olvides considerar responder tu pregunta

Comment: Si, se pudieron instalar bien. Esa fue la solución, muchas gracias!

Comment: Voy a tenerlo en cuenta. Me paso lo mismo con una pagina web hecha en react, gracias.